# How can recover message in Nifi about kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

Scenario:

As ConsumeKafka_2_0 consumes messages in Kafka,the offset in Kafka would becomes `100`.When Nifi is broken,make Nifi to restore to a past state with offset in Kafaka is `50`.However,actually the offset in Kafka is "100" because Kafka does not restore.

When Nifi is restarted,i guess that it consume messages from offset "100" rather than offset "50" because offset is "100" in Kafka at that time.So some messages of offset is "50" - "100" would loss?How can recover them?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka tracks the offset based on the Consumer Group Id (just called Group Id in the NiFi processor). So if you stop and start the processor without changing the group id, it will always start from the next offset for that group id.

NiFi does not currently have a way to start at a specific offset, but if you change the group id and select "Offset Reset" as "earliest", then it will start consuming from the beginning at offset 0.

Once data is consume from kafka and written to NiFi's repositories, the offset is then committed. So restarting NiFi doesn't need to reconsume those messages, they are already stored locally in NiFi, and NiFi will continue processing them from wherever they were in the flow when you restarted NiFi.

Comment: Thank you.i understand that nifi restarted avoid data to loss because of repo.What about Roll back the nifi with repo?Nifi with the repositiories ROLL BACK to the past,partial data  used to be in the repo and kafka which would loss?

Comment: There is no way to rollback NiFi's repositories, unless I don't understand

Comment: Scenario:KAFKA->NIFI->DB,there are spareta in different vitrual machines 1(VM1);if VM1 where NIFI in is broken,VM1 can't be started except to recover pasted VM1.However,the offset in Kafka is currently rather than pastly,and can't get data from kafka and repo.....